# How to display an html code on android application

Tags: android

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Company Name -MyCompany Inc.</title>
</head>
<body><strong >My<font color ='ORANGE'>Company </font>Inc.</strong>
<br><font face='Times New Roman' size='2' color ='#0000A0'><b>CONTACT DETAILS</b> </font></br>Address
<br> 
<br> Phone:</font> 1-xxx-xxx-xxxx x100 
<br>Fax:</font> 1-xxx-xxx-xxxx
<br><font color ='#0000A0'><b>Website:</b></font>
www.mycompany.com<br><font color ='BLACK' size ='1' face= 'calibri' ><b>Version : 1.008   </b></font> <br><font color ='BLACK' size ='1' face= 'calibri' ><b> Copyright @2011 myCompany Inc., ALL Rights Reserved</b></font><br></body></html>
```

I want to display this code in textview.
Can anybody help me?

Comment: You need WebView in order to display such HTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some HTML formatting can be displayed if you use **TextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(strMyHtmlString));**

If that doesn't do everything you want, I would use a **WebView**

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the documentation for the HTML element in Android:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html

Specifically, you're going to want to look at the fromHhml() method.

Answer (score 1):

```
yourTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml("YourHTML"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Best of my knowledge you can not display full html in Textview. WebView will solve your issue but If you want to make link enable for email, phone numnber, then It is possible.

```
 Linkify.addLinks(text, Linkify.PHONE_NUMBERS | Linkify.WEB_URLS);

    // Recognize all of the default link text patterns 
    Linkify.addLinks(text, Linkify.ALL);

    // Disable all default link detection
    Linkify.addLinks(text, 0);
```

Comment: No, i do not want to make links. Thanks

Comment: TextView is not for display HTML, I think you need to use WebView for your requirement,